# Distribute Firefox add-on internally

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

We (company) are developing a Firefox addon intended to ease the work performed on a department. The addon was developed to communicate specifically with our software.

I wanted to know if there's a way to distribute this addon internally, from a local server, instead of publishing it to AMO (https://addons.mozilla.org/). It would be nice if the internal employes could target our server so any changes in the extension would automatically be updated on client machines.

Is it possible? Could you provide me some guidelines regarding this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there a way to distribute an addon internally from a local server

> instead of publishing it to AMO (https://addons.mozilla.org/)

You can do this by specifying an [updateURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#updateURL) in the manifest for your add-on.

The periodic check for updates can also be done manually by the end users.

---

#### Automatic Add-on Update Checking

> Applications will periodically check for updates to installed add-ons
> by retrieving the [updateURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#updateURL). The information returned can be used
> to notify the user of an updated version to the add-on as well as
> inform the application of new application versions that the add-on is
> compatible with.

Source [Extension Versioning, Update and Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Extension_Versioning,_Update_and_Compatibility)

---

#### updateURL

> A link to a custom Update Manifest file that specifies available
> updates to the add-on. The format is described below. If enabled, the
> add-on manager periodically checks with this Manifest file to
> determine if newer versions are available. **When not included, the
> add-on manager will still check for updates on AMO, using the ID of
> the extension**.

...

> **Examples**
>
> ```
> <em:updateURL>http://www.foo.com/update.cgi?id=%ITEM_ID%&amp;version=%ITEM_VERSION%</em:updateURL>
> <em:updateURL>http://www.foo.com/extension/windows.rdf</em:updateURL>
> ```
>
> For add-ons hosted on addons.mozilla.org: You may not specify an updateURL property. By default, Mozilla applications using the Add-on Manager (such as Firefox and Thunderbird) will send update requests to addons.mozilla.org using the default web service. Every time you upload a new version of your add-on or change its compatibility parameters through the author interface, your update manifest will be generated automatically.
>
> **Format of the Update Manifest**:
>
> The Update Manifest is a RDF/XML
> datasource. For an example of an update manifest, see [Extension
> Versioning, Update and
> Compatibility.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extension_Versioning,_Update_and_Compatibility#Update_RDF_Format)

Source [updateURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#updateURL)